# How do I crop an image for screen size rather than resizing it in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So I'm developing a web page and the top section of this page has a tiny column in the right side, and to the left of it an image which is occupying the rest of the section and causing my problem.

The issue is that the image extends beyond the device's screen size missing up the layout of the page. Now I don't want to resize it to fit, but rather *crop* the extra width from the image according the screen size, so that it look the same but you can't horizontally scroll through the page which is what I'm experiencing right now.

I don't really know if that makes sense but if you have any idea on how to solve this please write it here and I will try it.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` on the container of the image?

Comment: Oh that solved the issue of cropping the image, now I see that I have the image cropped to the size of the container having it margined from the left, is there any thing I can do to have extends all the way ignoring the margin of parent elements?

Comment: do you actually mean `margin`? or do you mean `padding` of the parent element. In that case you could give it a negative marhin on the image that equals the padding of the parent element.

Comment: Thanks a lot this actually completely solves my problem.

Comment: Your problem description is still quite abstract. You should have added example output (screen shot) of the problem (and the final solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To crop the image without resizing it you have to apply `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element.

To counter the `padding` of the parent element you have to set a negative `margin` that equals the `padding` of the parent.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  margin: -20px;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x200.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You change your img tag for a div with background of the img (I suppose you have img tag, you didn't specify). The div then won't exceed the boundaries regardless the img inside it.

```
<div id="img"></div>
<style>
    #img {
       background: url("your img");
    } 
</style>
// Use this instead of <img src="your img">
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but for some reason it's hard to position the background just the way I want it, thanks for your answer I'll update the question with the best answer I received.